# HTML5 - When do you use <p>?

Tags: html, margin, padding, article, paragraph

When do you use `<p>`? I know it could be used for text, but do you need to write it if you have already -for example- `<article>`? or can I just use `<article>` alone then?

Also **why** do you need to use margin instead of padding on `<p>`? I tried already with padding, but that doesn't work. If I tried it with margin it works well.

Comment: When you want to mark up text as a _paragraph_. Period.

Comment: Well, look at the question you just wrote. Notice you split your question text into two segments. Those segments are paragraphs. So you would mark up each one of them in its own `<p>` element. This is independent of how the question itself is marked up. The question about margins vs padding is a separate question more pertinent to CSS than HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML `<p>` tag is used for [defining a paragraph](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html). For example the two sections of your question are paragraphs

Also to add  a margin is the space outside something, whereas padding is the space inside something.

For example:

```
h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

This leaves a 10-pixel width space around the secondary header and the header itself is fat from the 20-pixel width padding.

Comment: Everything after "Also to add" is lifted from http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/margins/ Also, the edit takes from my comment, but I'm not particularly concerned with that since I was the one who chose to post a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use margin to separate the content from things outside it.
2. Use padding to move the content away from the edges of the block.